# Asynchronous CRUD operations with express

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I have a basic CRUD application using html forms, nodejs/express and mongodb. I have been learning about synchronous vs asynchronous code via callbacks, promises, and async/await and to my understanding for a crud application you would want the operations to be asynchronous so multiple users can do the operations at the same time. I am trying to implement aync/await with my express crud operations and am not sure if they are executing synchronously or asynchronously.

Here is my update function, which allows a user to type in the _id of the blog they want to change, then type in a new title and new body for the blog and submit it. In its current state, to my knowledge it is executing synchronously:

```
app.post('/update', (req, res) => {
    const oldValue = { _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(String(req.body.previousValue)) }
    const newValues = { $set: { blogTitle: req.body.newValue, blogBody: req.body.newValue2 } }
    db.collection("miscData").updateOne(oldValue, newValues, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document updated");
        res.redirect('/')
    });

})
```

The way in which I was going to change this to asynchronous was this way:

```
app.post('/update', async (req, res) => {
    const oldValue = { _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(String(req.body.previousValue)) }
    const newValues = { $set: { blogTitle: req.body.newValue, blogBody: req.body.newValue2 } }
    await db.collection("miscData").updateOne(oldValue, newValues, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document updated");
        res.redirect('/')
    });

})
```

Both blocks of code work, however I am not sure if the second block of code is doing what I am intending it to do, which is allow a user to update a blog without blocking the call stack, or if the second block of code would only make sense if I was running more functions after the await. Does this achieve the intended purpose, if not how could/should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.collection(...).updateOne` is *always* asynchronous, so you need not worry that a long-running database operation might block your application. There are two ways how you can obtain the asynchronous result:

#### With a callback function

```
db.collection(...).updateOne(oldValues, newValues, function(err, result) {...});
console.log("This happens synchronously");
```

The callback function with the two parameters `(err, result)` will be called asynchronously, after the database operation has completed (and after the `console.log`). Either `err` contains a database error message or `result` contains the database result.

#### With promises

```
try {
  var result = await db.collection(...).updateOne(oldValues, newValues);
  // Do something with result
} catch(err) {
  // Do something with err
}
console.log("This happens asynchronously");
```

The `updateOne` function without a callback function as third parameter returns a promise that must be `await`ed. The statements that do something with `result` will be executed asynchronously, after the database operation has successfully completed. If a database error occurs, the statements in the `catch` block are executed instead. In either case (success or error), the `console.log` is only executed afterwards.

(If `updateOne` does not have a two-parameter version, you can write

```
var result = await util.promisify(db.collection(...).updateOne)(oldValues, newValues);
```

using [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal).)

Your second code snippet contains a mixture of both ways (third parameter plus `await`), which does not make sense.

Comment: This answered most of my question. I am wondering though, you say that updateOne is always asynchronous yet there are two ways to acheive asynchronous results? I am confused if that operation is always asynchronous and also if every mongodb method happens asynchronously as well. I think I am tracking with your post though I have read through it a few times now. Last question is just to confirm the first code snippet is running asynchronously and will not block code, is that correct?

Comment: Correct, while you wait for the asynchronous result, the Javascript engine processes other requests.